# How to show only the last record in a view ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am developping a ASP MVC project using Stored Procedures (Without Entity Framework).

After setting data in a formulaire, I want to show only the last record and not getting all the data from my database.

I know that I can write another method that select only the last record but I wonder if there is a solution to retrieve that from the view.

This is what I ve tried :

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) { 
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
            </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date.Date)
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Time)
                   </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nbre_P)
                   </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nbre_P)
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items)
                   </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items)
                </td>
                   </tr>

        } }
```

The Model Bestellung.cs :

```
public class Bestellung
{
    public int BestellungId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    public int Nbre_P { get; set; }

    public string Items { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
    public String Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you only want to show the last record in your view, then why are you querying for multiple records from the database? And why are you passing multiple records to your view? Just query for what you need, and pass only what you need to your view.

Comment: yes I know but the multiple query are used for another view

Comment: What is a `model` here? It should be a collection so u can iterate over it. Ideally, you should have taken only last record but as per your requirement, it makes sense to fetch last record in variable `var lastRecord = model.LastOrDefault();` OR` var lastRecord = model[model.count-1];' . You don't need a loop in that case

Comment: Thank you guys but the suggestion of mjwills works perfectly,
@mjwills can you please post your solution in answer that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to change:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

to:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Reverse().Take(1))
```

This still keeps the loop structure (i.e. the `foreach`), but ensures it will only ever process the last item in the original `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `Model` is of `IEnumerable<T>` type not sure why can't you just use LINQ [`Last()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns the last element

Comment: because the model doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator

Comment: @Exact, post he type of `Model`

Comment: @Exact, so from your controller you are passing the individual instance or a list?

Comment: I pass an instance, I can post for you the code of controller if you want to see how it is work but I fix already the problem using Model.Reverse().Take(1))

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that.

If you filter it in the view, which is possible but I wouldn't recommend it, you habe the whole list model items loaded. Why would you even want to do it?

It's the task of the controller to filter your data and ONLY send the needed items. 
In the controller call

```
Model.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: the model doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator and  I find the solution, I have to use  Model.Reverse().Take(1))

Comment: May I ask which type your Model has?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the last record and not getting all the data from my database.
you can use this :

in controller :

```
var Bestellung = db.Bestellungs.OrderByDescending(p => p.BestellungId ).FirstOrDefault();
```

will get you the very last record from a Bestellungs

Answer (score -1):

try this.No need to iterate any loop

```
<tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().FirstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Address)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Email)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Phone)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Date.Date)
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Time)
               </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Time)
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nbre_P)
               </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Nbre_P)
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items)
               </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastOrDefault().Items)
            </td>
               </tr>
```

Comment: This method is too redundant. There is no need to call LastOrDefault() over and over again

Comment: Do you realize you are probably going to call 'LastOrdefault' multiple times which could have been cached in a variable.

Answer (score -3):

Your model should be list of modelobject not only model
Better to store your object in list of objects like that

```
  class viewmodel
  {
      public  list<yourclassname> propertyname; 
  }
```

and used this viewmodel class in view page

```
@foreach(var item in Model.PropertyName.lastordefault())
```

Comment: the model doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator

Comment: Ienumureble is there which you can use and then you can loop through how it mentioned above

Comment: or you can use like that 
@model  "your viewmodel"
your viewmodel will contain that list of object property which you need to loop through and get last record

Comment: thank for trying to help but I find tghe solution, I have to use Model.Reverse().Take(1)

Comment: BUt without list how you would get reverse and take 1 ?

Comment: Or if it work then simple you can take LastOrDefault()
this can be cause performance issue if your model is too big

Comment: `Model` can be of type `IEnumerable<T>`